# Greene and Krantz Chapter 4, Question 8b Riemann's theorem for removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $U = D(P,r) \setminus \{P\}$. Prove the following refined versions of Riemann's theorem. If $f$ is holomorphic on $U$ and if $\int_U |f(z)|^2 \, dx \, dy < \infty$ then $f$ extends holomorphically across $P$.

Hint: If $F$ is a holomorphic function on $D(Q,\epsilon)$ then
$$|F(Q)|^2 \leq \frac{1}{\pi \epsilon^2} \int_{D(Q,\epsilon)} |F(z)|^2 \, dx \, dy$$
Use this to prove that $F$ as in the statement of the problem has at most a simple pole or removable singularity at $P$. Then, show that $\int |F|^2 = +\infty$ if $F$ has a pole.

My attempt: If for a contradiction that $f$ admits an essential singularity at $P$ then $f(U)$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{C}$. So, by Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality,
$$+ \infty = \int_U |f(z)|\, dx \, dy \leq \left( \int_U |f(z)|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_U \, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} = \left( \int_U |f(z)|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} \cdot\ (\text{volume of}\ U)^{1/2}$$
reaching a contradiction. However, to prove that $f$ admits at most a simple pole at $P$ consider the function $F(z) := (z-P) f(z)$ by Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality,
$$\int_U |F(z)|\, dx \, dy \leq \left( \int_U |z-P|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} \left( \int_U |f(z)|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2}  < \infty$$

**From this can I assume that $F$ is bounded in $U$?**  If so, then $f$ has either a simple pole at $P$ or removable singularity at $P$. If $f$ has a simple pole at $P$, then $\lim_{z \to P} |f(z)| = +\infty$ so there exists $\epsilon >0$ so that $D(P, \epsilon)\setminus \{P\} \subset U$ and there exists $M >0$ so that
$$z \in D(P, \epsilon)\setminus \{P\}  \implies |f(z)| > M$$
So,
\begin{align*}
M\cdot\ (\text{volume of}\ (D(P, \epsilon)\setminus \{P\} ) &\leq \int_{D(P, \epsilon)\setminus \{P\} }|f(z)|\, dx \, dy\\
&\leq \int_U |f(z)\, dx \, dy\\
&\leq \left( \int_U |f(z)|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} \left(\int_U \, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left( \int_U |f(z)|^2\, dx \, dy \right)^{1/2} \cdot\ (\text{volume of}\ U)^{1/2}\\
&< +\infty.
\end{align*}
But allowing $M \to +\infty$ we reach a contradiction. May I know this approach is sound? As I did not use the hint directly in my attempt. Any hints/solutions are appreciated.